# Setting PowerBi filter on Report Load and maintaining dataColor order

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm trying to set a PowerBi report filter on load but also maintain my dataColors array position. I've created a video to illustrate my issue - I hope that's allowed...

https://www.loom.com/share/40f0040311ee4487a46a0ad23c6ea1c9

When I apply a filter the behaviour differs to selecting the filter in the UI. I guess it's because as there is only one strand of data on load that it takes the first data colour from the array but I'd like to maintain this order.

Any help appreciated - cheers!

Rob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to maintain the dataColors array position w.r.t filters / data. The dataColors array within the themes file will be applied sequentially. Color at position one will be applied to the very first data strand that was specified in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks @mayur_007X that's my understanding too. Shame.